# RequestsCookieJar[] is empty

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://watchdisneychannel.go.com/live')
>>> r.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

my question is why cookies are empty? I can see them in browser.
same code works for google:

```
>>> print requests.get('http://google.com').cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie NID=78=UM96VYrGN8qukZRUyN2irFxNXLipsiFs9PpQvlu7fKEC3b9RS_cRLWAegWDoVj8642Qsq5ILhGEx6aNYusaoGQu3YNlyuu7rYfQLd_ZgtUTyRLE7n1V6a9S71xhAWMJ-E5OUy1yTT0siQno for .google.com/>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the cookies from `http://watchdisneychannel.go.com/live` are invalid which python ignores. You need to prepare and load cookies manually to make them work https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html#http.cookies.BaseCookie.load